# How to handle OTP popup?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to inspect elements on the webpage but as soon as popup comes it shows an error of element not visible.

[image]

I am using correct locators for the same, also I tried using different timeouts for the thread.

Sleep it is not working.

When I click on view source it is showing the same frame as well.

I wrote the below code:

```java
\\\
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class INDIALENDS {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://indialends.com/");  
driver.manage().window().maximize();
String s=driver.getCurrentUrl();

System.out.println(s);
driver.getTitle();
String x=driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(x);
\\\


\\\
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Personal Loan")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("li_display_name")).sendKeys("RAVNEET KAUR");
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("ravneetkaur@indialends.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("pincode")).sendKeys("122018");
driver.findElement(By.id("employment")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("salaried12")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.id("companyName")).sendKeys("INDIALENDS");

Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.id("monthlyIncome")).sendKeys("34000");
driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("5282273663");
driver.findElement(By.id("li_submit")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
\\\


\\\
Thread.sleep(25000);
driver.findElement(By.id("li_submit")).click();
Thread.sleep(25000);
//new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("control__indicator")));
driver.findElement(By.id("li_agree")).click();
String s2=driver.getCurrentUrl();
\\\

\\\
System.out.println(s2);
driver.getTitle();
String x1=driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(x1);
Thread.sleep(5000);

}
}
\\\
```

Comment: For which line of code do you see _`element not visible`_ error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the full code. Please try it from your end.

```
public class MyTesting {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Swaroop\\ChromeVersion87\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://indialends.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String s = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    System.out.println(s);
    driver.getTitle();
    String x = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(x);

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Personal Loan")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("li_display_name")).sendKeys("RAVNEET KAUR");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("ravneetkaur@indialends.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("pincode")).sendKeys("122018");
    driver.findElement(By.id("employment")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("salaried12")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.id("companyName")).sendKeys("INDIALENDS");

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("monthlyIncome")).sendKeys("34000");
    driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("5282273663");
    driver.findElement(By.id("li_submit")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("control-indicator"))).click();
    String s2 = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    System.out.println(s2);
    driver.getTitle();
    String x1 = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(x1);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: no this didn't worked I am getting this Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
@swaroop humane

Comment: thanks sir this worked issue was thread.sleep()